# How do I reference a file stored in internal storage from a WebView?

Tags: android, webview

I have some files stored in the app's "internal storage", which is located on the device here:

> /data/data//files/

Here's the problem: I want to reference these files from the webview. How do I do this? What should I use as the baseUrl?

I need something similar to file:///android_asset but for "internal storage" instead of for files in the assets directory.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
file:///data/data/com.yourproject.example/files/image.png
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use [Context.getFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29) when generating the path, not hard coding the application's files-path. This will ensure that the application will still work even if your package/namespace changes.

Example:

```java
String filesPath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
String filePath = "file://" + filesPath + "/image.png";
```